# Hostinger error, Strict Standards Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, uri

```
<section class="vbox">
    <header class="bg-dark lt header navbar navbar-fixed-top-xs">
        <?php $uri = end( explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>
        <div class="navbar-header bg-dark aside-md"> <a class="btn btn-link visible-xs" data-toggle="class:nav-off-screen,open" data-target="#nav,html"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="fullscreen"><img src="./files/logo.png" class="m-r-xs">ResidenConce</a> <a class="btn btn-link visible-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target=".nav-user"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> </a> </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-user m-n hidden-xs">
            <li class="hidden-xs"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dk" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-bell"></i> </a>
                <section class="dropdown-menu aside-xl">
                    <section class="panel bg-white">
                        <header class="panel-heading b-light bg-light"> <strong>Tienes <span class="count">0</span> notificaciones</strong> </header>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="thumb-sm avatar pull-left"> <img src="./files/avatar.jpg"> </span> <?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']) { ?>
                        <?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; ?> <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight">
                    <span class="arrow top"></span>
                    <li> <a href="profile.php">Ajustes</a> </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li> <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </header>
<section>
    ...
```

Gives me error in this line

```
<?php $uri = end( explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>
```

In localhost it works, but in Hostinger it's the error

please any solution, thanks ind advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) requires an array, not an expression resolved to array.

So:

```
<?php $uri = end( explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php 
    $requestUriArray = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    $uri = end($requestUriArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function has a parameter that passed by reference. So only need to use a variable to send this parameter:

```
$request_uri =  explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$uri = end($request_uri);
```